# where do I get openGL driver monitor?

Tags: macos

I stumbled upon this interesting [documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/OpenGLDriverMonitorUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) mentioning OpenGL Driver Monitor. So I searched for that tool but is nowhere to be found. How can I get that tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest version of Xcode (4.4), OpenGL Driver Monitor and similar tools are no longer included. You need to download "Graphics Tools for Xcode" from [Apple's Mac developer downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (requires free developer account).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?q=graphics

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install the developer tools, which is on the App Store for free if you have lion.  If not, you can download Xcode 3.2 from Apple's developer site.  Then, the app should be in /Developers/Application/Graphics Tool/

Comment: I installed xcode 4.3 from App store, I still don't see the driver monitor tool. I can see some other openGL ES performance tool though

Comment: Confirmed its where @theAmateurProgrammer says it should be in Xcode 3.2.6 and 4.2.1 (for Lion). Haven't tried 4.3 though.

Comment: Oh right, Xcode 4.3 is now just bundled as an app only. (aka, no more /Developers)  Somehow, I can't find the driver app anymore. But, the app OpenGL ES Performance Detective looks similar.  Open up Xcode 4.3, then click on Xcode-Developer Tools, then open the app up.  Check if it's similar.  If not, then go to this site https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20- (You might have to sign up for the free developer account) and download the Graphics Tool for Xcode bundle and see if any one of them are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find it in the Open GL ES Performance Detective. It is for iOS devices only. Instead open up Open GL Profiler and under Open GL Profiler's Views menu, you'll see Open GL Driver Monitor. You'll get these when you download the Graphics Tools bundle accessible from Xcode's Menu Xcode | Open Developer Tools | More Developer Tools.

You will need the developer tools installed and that will need an installation of Xcode 4.2.1 or earlier.

That said, it is a hack, I get this message on starting the Profiler

```
App version 4.6 (68) is not the same as nub version 4.5 (66) at path: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/PlugIns/GLProfilerFBDisp.bundle

Profiler will not function correctly and may quit unexpectedly
```

Yet it does work.